# If my iPhone 4 has spyware on it will encrypting my sms messages with an encryption app keep them private?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, sms

I am currently dealing with a stalking situation and my iPhone 4 is being monitored. The person knows all my phone info like meid, imei, phone number etc…  Also I believe my phone has spy software on it.

I have removed this before by restoring the phone to factory conditions through iTunes, however, I now think they can install it remotely. If I use an app that does SMS encryption in your opinion do you think that will keep my texts private?

Answer (score 2):

It is ***extremely*** improbable that your iPhone 4 with the latest software, without jailbreak, has a spyware on it, especially if nobody else than you had physical access to your phone after jailbreak.

However if someone has remote access to your phone communications through "encrypted" messagging apps *should* be quite safe for itself, **but** if you have a spyware on your phone be sure that someone could see you screen as you see it, for example when you type and read messages in the "encrypted app".

Answer (score 1):

Unless your iPhone 4 is jailbroken, it is very unlikely that anyone can remotely install any spyware. It would normally require physical access to your phone, along with your passcode, then your Apple ID and password as well.

A more plausible possibility is that this person knows your iCloud or Apple ID and password, and is logged into your iCloud account so he/she can see your messages.

I would go [here](https://www.apple.com/support/appleid/) and change your Apple ID / iCloud password immediately.